# what does "Sometype* const*" signifies?

Tags: c++, constants

what does "Sometype* const*" signifies ?

Is it equivalent to const SomeType* ?

I ran across it in the find Key function for TMap data structure in UE4 and its the first time I'm seeing something like this.

Needless to say I couldn't make sense out of it and think of any types that can store it

[image]

Comment: It is a pointer to a constant pointer to a (non-constant) `Sometype`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude PointerCeption?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const

Comment: This site is for `C` but in this case the results are equivalent to the ones in `C++`: [`int * const * value;`](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+*+const+*+value%3B) vs [`const int * value;`](http://cdecl.org/?q=const+int+*+value%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's unpick it, considering a simpler, more familiar case first:

`Sometype**` is a pointer to a pointer to a non-`const` `Sometype` object.

`Sometype* const*` is a pointer to a `const`-pointer to a non-`const` `Sometype` object.

Comment: I see! make sense since const sometype* is taken for constant pointers